# Remove multi-selected rows correctly from QListView

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistview

I am having issues trying to correctly delete  multiple selected rows from a QListView. It works correctly selecting items going from top to bottom, but when you select multiple rows going from bottom to top, it keeps one of the selected rows in the view.

How can I fix this to where it correctly removes all selected rows in any order the user chooses?

Example:

Selecting the rows in this order gives an invalid solution:
Level5, Level3, Level2

Removes only Level2

Changing to `for items in self.listView.selectedIndexes():` works the opposite to where you cannot select from top to bottom.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys,functools

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setCentralWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget(self))
        self.setWindowTitle('GUI')
        mainlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        #Information for widgets
        self.items = {'Level1':1,'Level2':2,'Level3':3,'Level4':4,'Level5':5,'Level6':6}
        #LineEdit1
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.button.setText('Remove Selected Items')
        firstBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        firstBox.addWidget(self.button)
        #ListView
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.listView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        secondBox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        secondBox.addWidget(self.listView)

        #Add Layouts
        mainlayout.addLayout(firstBox)
        mainlayout.addLayout(secondBox)
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(mainlayout)
        #Model
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView.setModel(self.model)

        self.button.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.selecteditems,self.model))
        self.fillModel(self.model)

    def fillModel(self,model):
        for level in self.items:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(level))
            model.appendRow(item)

    def selecteditems(self,model):
        if len(self.listView.selectedIndexes()) > 1:
            for items in reversed(self.listView.selectedIndexes()):
                model.takeRow(items.row()) #works correctly selecting items from top to bottom, but doesn't work when selecting bottom to top
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: As an alternative: sometimes the best way to handle a view is not to directly try to manipulate the view but create an object that either feeds the view directly (via a data link) or indirectly and then manipulate that object instead of the view.  For instance (indirectly) if you had an Array (List or Dictionary) that contained your View then when things are selected you get what was selected adjust your Array and then clear and reload your View -- if you are dealing with large amounts of data only show in the view what fits comfortably and page the data via code rather than scroll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also use just `reversed` and `sorted`:

```
def selecteditems(self,model):
    if len(self.listView.selectedIndexes()) > 1:
        for items in reversed(sorted(self.listView.selectedIndexes())):
            model.takeRow(items.row())
```

Comment: The `if` prevents single selected items to get deleted. Intentional?

Comment: probably OP has some reason for that, I was concentate to the main problem of deleting all selected rows :)

Comment: Answer worked as expected, just wondering but when I implement a QSortFilterProxyModel and I have a QLineEdit that takes text which filters out the Levels, how can I remove that item from QListView, or is this question best served as a new post entirely?

Comment: I suggest you write a new post, so you can get more solutions with better  and more detailed explanations